# What is Ryu-Takayanagi Entanglement Entropy?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

I have a question about how to think about the Ryu-Takayanagi entanglement entropy mathematically.

For simplicity, let's work in the simplified setting of a time-symmetric slice of $AdS_4$ space -- i.e., hyperbolic three space $\mathbb{H}^3$.

In this case, if I am understanding things correctly, given a region $A$ in the ideal boundary $\partial \mathbb{H}^3$ with boundary $\gamma=\partial A$, Ryu-Takayanagi define their entanglement entropy to be the "area" of an area minimizing surface, $\Sigma$, in $\mathbb{H}^3$ that has asymptotic boundary $\gamma$.

Of course, this area is infinite so what one looks at is some sort of asymptotic expansion.  My understanding of this (based off of papers of [Alexakis and Mazzeo](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2250)) is that this is done via some choice of boundary defining function $b$.   Following work of Graham and Witten , this yields an asymptotic expansion for the area

$$
Area(\Sigma\cap \{ b>\epsilon\})=Length(\gamma)\epsilon^{-1}+\mathcal{A}(\Sigma)+O(\epsilon)
$$
where here $\mathcal{A}(\Sigma)$ is the renormalized area of $\Sigma$.

Of course the leading order term depends, in on the choice of boundary defining function (which I believe allows one to fix a metric on the boundary in order to also make sense of the length but I may be mistaken).

My question is what is the correct notion of entanglement entropy in this case?  Ryu-Takayanagi seem to suggest it is the full expansion (which seems to require the additional data of the boundary defining function) whereas if I understand Alexakis and Mazzeo's paper correctly they take it as the renormalized area.